# Lagrange Undetermined Multipler

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Q1) Write down the Lagrangian of the system in terms of y(t)
Q2) Obtain the Eqn of motion
Q3)Using Lagrange Multiplier method find the forces of constraints
1)
We have a constraint such that $$f=y-r\theta=0 $$

And the lagrangian is

$$L=1/2m[\dot{y}^2+\frac{R^2\dot{\theta}^2}{2}]+mgy$$

from here I have to get rid of the $\theta$ by using constraint.
Then I get

$$L=1/2m[\dot{y}^2+\frac{\dot{y}^2}{2}]+mgy$$

$$\ddot{y}=2g/3$$ where g is gravity of earth.

Now the question asks to find the constraints so

I dont use the constraint in the lagrangian and I just wrote the Multipler equation which it is

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_j}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j} = \sum {\lambda_j}\frac{\partial {f_j}}{\partial q_i}$$

From here I get two equations

$$m\ddot{y}-mg=\lambda$$
$$mR^2\ddot{\theta}=-\lambda R$$

But I dont know how to proceed to find the force of constraint, thanks

Comment: I'm guessing your Lagrangian is incorrect - which could easily be a typesetting problem. If I use $L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{y}^{2}+r^{2}\dot{\theta}^{2})-mgy$ as the Lagrangian instead, I get a constraint force of $\ddot y=-\frac{g}{2}$. But you had right idea - in the end you need to eliminate $\lambda$ to find the force of constraint.

Comment: Its not a type. This is a given lagrange for the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last equations should be
\begin{align}
&m\ddot{y} = \lambda + mg\\
&\frac{mR^2}{2}\ddot{\theta} = - \lambda R
\end{align}
The equations can be slightly simplified to 
\begin{align}
&m\ddot{y} = \lambda + mg\\
&mR\ddot{\theta} = - 2\lambda
\end{align}

The constraint $y - R \theta = 0$ can be multipled by the mass $m$, which yields
$$my - R^2\theta = 0$$
Now, differentiate it twice with respect to time $t$
$$m\ddot{y} - mR\ddot{\theta} = 0 $$
Next, plug in the twice differentiated constraint the expressions for the second derivatives from the system of differential equations
$$0 = m\ddot{y} - mR\ddot{\theta}  = \lambda + mg - (-2\lambda) = 3\lambda + mg$$ Now, solve for $\lambda$
$$\lambda = -\frac{1}{3}mg$$ Finally, your constrained equations become
\begin{align}
&m\ddot{y} = \lambda + mg = -\frac{1}{3}mg + mg = \frac{2}{3}mg\\
&mR\ddot{\theta} = - \lambda = \frac{1}{3}mg
\end{align} which after cancelling out the mass turn into
\begin{align}
&\ddot{y} = \frac{2g}{3}\\
&\ddot{\theta} = \frac{g}{3R}
\end{align}